# "Run-time error '1004' PrintOut method of Worksheet class failed" after saving Excel worksheet to .pdf

Tags: excel, vba, macos, runtime-error

I am trying to write an Excel for Mac VBA macro to print a worksheet and then save it as a .pdf file.  I keep getting "Run-time error '1004' PrintOut method of Worksheet class failed".

So I opened a new Workbook and saved it as macro enabled Book1.xlsm.  I then generated the following macro

```
Sub PrintAndSaveAsPDF()
'Print the active sheet
  ActiveSheet.PrintOut
'Save the active sheet as a .pdf file
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=0, _
        FileName:="Sheet1.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

This macro works perfectly the first time.  It prints the active sheet and then saves it as sheet1.pdf in the folder that contains Book1.xlsm.  However if I delete sheet1.pdf and run the macro again I get

> "Run-time error '1004' PrintOut method of Worksheet class failed".

It seems that the ExportAsFixedFormat blocks access to the default printer.  I have tried all the suggestions I can find on the internet but none solve the problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.

For reference I am running Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16.72 (23040900) in macOS Monterey Version 12.2.1

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the use of `ActiveSheet` - Try replacing `ActiveSheet` with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` *if you sheet is called "Sheet1". Then try again. If the error persists it's not the problem if it fixes the error you at least have the source of the error (so basically debugging)

Comment: Also instead of `FileName:="Sheet1.pdf"` do `FileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\Sheet1.pdf"` this way you are reliably saving in the folder where the WB sits. Saving it without the full Path can lead to problems down the road (for example on network drives)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but with those changes,  I still get the same error.