# Excel/VBA / "Run-time error '1004': Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object 'Range' failed"

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to save some range from a page "offer" to a pdf file. Before this VBA worked smoothly but something went wrong.

I have the following VBA code:

```vb
Sub Save_pdf()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim pdf_rng As Range
    Dim Name As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Offer")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If cell.Value = "x" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    lastRow = ws.Range("J" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = lastRow + 4
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "J32:Q" & lastRow
    
    Set pdf_rng = ws.Range("J32:Q" & lastRow)
    
    'Pdf file's name is equal to file's name
    'Name = ws.FullName
    'Name = Left(Nm, InStrRev(Nm, ".") - 1) & Format(Now, " yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".pdf"
    
    'Pdf file's name is equal to sheet's name
    Name = ws.Name
    Name = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Name & Format(Now, " yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".pdf"
    
    pdf_rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=Name, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
 
End Sub
```

After executing this code I have the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'ExportAsFixedFormat' of object 'Range' failed

I was trying to debug this but nothing helps...

It looks like that variables are fine
[image: variables]

Tried to debug changing
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("offer") to ActiveWorkSheet

If it would be easier I may send the file.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "/"` ? Is this on a Mac

Comment: Yeah, it's Mac OS

Comment: You gotta decide where this will be happening: in some random active sheet or the worksheet `Offer` in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`). If the latter, start with `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook: Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Offer")` and replace all occurrences of `ActiveSheet` with `ws`. Instead of the forward or backward slash you can use `Application.PathSeparator` to make it work in any system. `lastCell` represents a worksheet row so rename it to `lastRow`. And qualify **all** objects e.g. `ws.Range("J" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: Valuable advices. Make corrections but the error is not fixed.

Comment: Could you explain which rows you actually want to hide? What is the used range address? What is in `J32:Q32`, headers? What's with the additional 4 rows at the bottom? Is that a footer? Since you're copying a range, you should `IgnorePrintAreas:=True`. Maybe it would be best for you to share a screenshot of your worksheet. Also, add to the bottom of your post what your code looks like after the  corrections you recently made.

Comment: 1. J32:Q32 - just additional empty space to make data look accurate,  +4 rows added for the same reason. 2. I would like to hide all empty rows 3. This code worked before as expected but not clear why now it shows error

Comment: I've tried the code in your worksheet and it works. Have you recently closed Excel? Try that, everything is fine on my end (on Windows, though).

Comment: try with `OpenAfterPublish:=False`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76159027/

Comment: Opened / closed excel.  Changed OpenAfterPublish to False.  Doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you print a selection to PDF manually ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes I can

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, here are some changed.

```
Sub Save_pdf()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Long
    Dim pdf_rng As Range
    Dim Nm As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If cell.Value = "x" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    lastCell = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCell = lastCell + 4
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("offer")
    Set pdf_rng = ws.Range("J32:Q" & lastCell)
    
    ' Ensure the path exists
    If Len(Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Path not found: " & ThisWorkbook.Path
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set name equal to sheet's name
    Nm = ws.Name
    Nm = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Nm & Format(Now, " yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".pdf"
    
    pdf_rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        fileName:=Nm, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Unfortunately these adjustments doesn't help. I still have the same error.  Besides this advice (& "\" &) is not applicable to me, because I'm Mac OS user, so for me should be (& "/" &)

Comment: Strange. This code works fine in my PC (window 10).  I updated the full sub above,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the problem is in a location. A macro works if I save a file in default location

```vb
Name = ActiveSheet.Name 
Name = Name & ".pdf"
```

but doesn't work in other cases. Meanwhile I'm an administrator user. Here is the post with explanation of the issue:

[Unable to save as PDF from VBA in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148305/unable-to-save-as-pdf-from-vba-in-mac)